# Getting Value from datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datetimepicker

Trying this in angular to get a value of the datetime-local datepicker. I have validatiors on my form control group so when i hit submit i am told it is an invalid form as the value for this is null HTML.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetime">Date:</label>
     <input type="datetime-local" formControlName="datetime"
            class="form-control" id="datetime" aria-describedby="datetime" 
            placeholder="datetime" >
     <small id="passHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>
```

I was able to set the date value in my typescript file by hardcoding it however this was the only time i was able to submit the form. Even changing this would still just submit the original hardcoded value.